# Why doesn't the build method of child get called when parent state changes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's my code in which i am running the `move` method on the `snake` object every second which changes the state of the snake (The snake is a normal class and just has some primitive types which get updated ) and calling the `setState` of the `SnakeBoard` class . The issue is that , i was expecting it to call the `build` method of even `BoardTile` class since it uses the same `snake` object which got changed inside the snake object.

Since the build method of `BoardTile` class doesn't get called at each second interval , the snake never moves. Why is this happening ? Please explain ....

```
class SnakeBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  List<BoardTile> _boardTiles ;
  List<BoardTile> get boardTiles => _boardTiles;

  set boardTiles(List<BoardTile> boardTiles) {
    _boardTiles = boardTiles;
  }
  Snake _snake ;

  Snake get snake => _snake;

  set snake(Snake snake) {
    _snake = snake;
  }

  SnakeBoard(){
    boardTiles = List.generate( 100 , (int index)=> BoardTile( index , this ) ) ;
    snake = Snake(10 , 10) ;
  }

  @override
  _SnakeBoardState createState() => _SnakeBoardState();
}

class _SnakeBoardState extends State<SnakeBoard> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child : GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 10,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: widget.boardTiles
        ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer){
      setState(() {
        widget.snake.move() ;
        print("Snaking moving !" ) ;
      });
    });
  }
}

class BoardTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id ;
  final SnakeBoard snakeBoard ;
  @override
  _BoardTileState createState() => _BoardTileState();

  BoardTile(this.id, this.snakeBoard);
}


class _BoardTileState extends State<BoardTile> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Snake snake = widget.snakeBoard.snake ;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration( border: Border.all(width: 1) ),
      child:
      snake.isPresent(widget.id) ? snake.getSnakePartWidget(widget.id)   : Text(widget.id.toString()) ,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without running your code, my general advise is to try and move the fields/attributes that make up your "state" (here: the `Snake`) from the `SnakeBoard` to the `_SnakeBoardState` class.

And to specifically address your question:

It would be reasonable for Flutter not to rebuild the `BoardTile`s (but instead reuse the old ones) because the snake is not part of the `BoardTile`s' state -- for that it would need to be a field in your `_BoardTileState` class.
Thus from Flutter's point of view the `BoardTile`'s state hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should call setState inside build method of BoardTile class instead of initState method SnakeBoard class.